# Can x-frame-options be used to allow specific websites to access content via iframe?

Tags: html, iframe, web, same-origin-policy

Sites will often set `x-frame-options` response header to `SAMEORIGIN` to stop other sites from including their content within an iframe.

I want to know if `x-frame-options` or **any** method at all can be used to stop non-affiliated sites from displaying the content while **allowing** partnered or affiliated sites to do so.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Of course you can.

Use `ALLOW-FROM uri`.

Read more on this at [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/HTTP/X-Frame-Options)